# fix orientation

Tags: android

Reading android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT I need fix orientation of my app. So, if version < 3 I need fix orientation to portrait.
Using this code does not run.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Be more specific on "Using this code does not run". Any crashlog? Or simply doesn't have any effect?

Comment: does it compile at least?

Comment: Sorry :-) no any effects.

Comment: Where do you call this method? I mean in which android callback?

Comment: I can not see the version  check

Comment: Maybe the method `setRequestedOrientation` it doesn't get called at all...?

Comment: `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=3)
    {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); Or setRequestedOrientation(1); //1=ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
     }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=3) 
 {
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); Or setRequestedOrientation(1); //1=ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
 }
else
 {
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR); or setRequestedOrientation(4); 4=ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR
 }
```

Comment: The code:  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) does not run. I try with simple project with an activity.

Comment: What android version do you have?